# GPU mouse picking OpenGL/WebGL

Tags: opengl, webgl, projection

I understand i need to render only 1x1 or 3x3 pixel part of the screen where the mouse is, with object id's as colors and then get id from the color.

I have implemented ray-cast picking with spheres and i am guessing it has something to do with making camera look in direction of the mouse ray?

How do i render the correct few pixels?

Edit:

setting camera in direction of mouse ray works, but if i make the viewport smaller the picture scales but what (i think) i need is for it to be cropped rather than scaled. How would i achieve this?

Comment: viewport and adjusting the projection matrix

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest solution is to use the scissor test. It allows you to render only pixels within a specified rectangular sub-region of your window.

For example, to limit your rendering to 3x3 pixels centered at pixel (x, y):

```
glScissor(x - 1, y - 1, 3, 3);
glEnable(GL_SCISSOR_TEST);
glDraw...(...);
glDisable(GL_SCISSOR_TEST);
```

Note that the origin of the coordinate system is at the bottom left of the window, while most window systems will give you mouse coordinates in a coordinate system that has its origin at the top left. If that's the case on your system, you will have to invert the y-coordinate by subtracting it from `windowHeight - 1`.

Comment: That is surely the easiest way. I implemented setting projection matrix looking in direction of mouse ray, zoomed in on the 1px area i need (FOV/screenWidth) and setting 1px viewport. It should be faster since faces are supposedly being skipped by fragment shader if they are outside view. If i understand correctly scissor works after fragment shader. My tests, however, didn't show significant performance difference.

Comment: The performance impact will likely be from the readpixels which causes the gpu and cpu to sync. Viewport and Scissor should be similar in performance, though scissor less complicated to match what is seen e.g. the view matrixes remain the same